# Mount zvol partition of filesystem type 'LVM2_member' which is a snapshot of a raw qcow2 export

Tags: mount, lvm, zfs, snapshot, volume

I'm currently trying to migrate some VMs which are stored in qcow2 files onto ZFS ZVOLs.

One of the things I want to do before deciding if I really want to stick with this is to see if I can make snapshots of the shut down VM and then mount the snapshot in read-only mode on the host in order to navigate it and view / copy files at will.

I had the following workflow:

Get info:

```
/kvm-images $ sudo qemu-img info Ubuntu-Server-20.04.qcow2

image: Ubuntu-Server-20.04.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 128 GiB (137438953472 bytes)
disk size: 41.4 GiB
cluster_size: 65536
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    compression type: zlib
    lazy refcounts: true
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false
    extended l2: false
```

Create ZVOL

```
/kvm-images $ sudo zfs create -V 137438953472 tank/kvm-images/Ubuntu-Server-20.04
```

Export image from qcow2 file to ZVOL

```
/kvm-images $ sudo qemu-img convert -O raw /kvm-images/Ubuntu-Server-20.04.qcow2 /dev/zvol/tank/kvm-images/Ubuntu-Server-20.04
```

Then modify the VM Virtio Disk 1 xml from

```
<disk type="file" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
  <source file="/kvm-images/Ubuntu-Server-20.04.qcow2"/>
  <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
  <boot order="1"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x03" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</disk>
```

to

```
<disk type="block" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="raw" cache="none" io="native" discard="unmap"/>
  <source dev="/dev/zvol/tank/kvm-images/Ubuntu-Server-20.04" index="2"/>
  <backingStore/>
  <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
  <boot order="1"/>
  <alias name="virtio-disk0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x03" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</disk>
```

Booting into the VM is possible, everything seems to behave as it used to.

So I shut down the VM and create a snapshot

```
/kvm-images $ sudo zfs snapshot tank/kvm-images/Ubuntu-Server-20.04@test-01
```

After issuing

```
sudo zfs set snapdev=visible tank/kvm-images/Ubuntu-Server-20.04
```

I'm able to see the partitions of the snapshot in `/dev/zvol/tank/kvm-images`

```
/dev/zvol/tank/kvm-images $ ls -lsah
total 0
0 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 280 Jul 25 16:31 .
0 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  80 Jul 25 11:47 ..
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Jul 25 15:53 Ubuntu-Server-20.04 -> ../../../zd48
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Jul 25 15:53 Ubuntu-Server-20.04-part1 -> ../../../zd48p1
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Jul 25 15:53 Ubuntu-Server-20.04-part2 -> ../../../zd48p2
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Jul 25 15:53 Ubuntu-Server-20.04-part3 -> ../../../zd48p3
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Jul 25 16:31 Ubuntu-Server-20.04@test-01 -> ../../../zd64
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Jul 25 16:31 Ubuntu-Server-20.04@test-01-part1 -> ../../../zd64p1
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Jul 25 16:31 Ubuntu-Server-20.04@test-01-part2 -> ../../../zd64p2
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Jul 25 16:31 Ubuntu-Server-20.04@test-01-part3 -> ../../../zd64p3
```

Trying to use `zfs mount` does not work,

```
sudo zfs mount tank/kvm-images/Ubuntu-Server-20.04@test-01
```

fails to autocomplete after Ubuntu-Server-20.04, and if forced mentions

```
cannot open 'tank/kvm-images/Ubuntu-Server-20.04@test-01': snapshot delimiter '@' is not expected here
```

So I try to mount it manually as if it were legacy:

```
sudo mount /dev/zvol/tank/kvm-images/Ubuntu-Server-20.04@test-01-part3 /mnt/snapshots/ubuntu

mount: /mnt/snapshots/ubuntu: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
```

Partition 2 (`Ubuntu-Server-20.04@test-01-part2`) is mountable and navigable, it contains the `/boot` partition.

Issuing `sudo vgscan --mknodes` yields

```
WARNING: Not using device /dev/zd64p3 for PV aaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaa.
WARNING: PV aaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaa prefers device /dev/zd48p3 because device is used by LV.
Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
WARNING: Not using device /dev/zd64p3 for PV aaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaa.
WARNING: PV aaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaa prefers device /dev/zd48p3 because device is used by LV.
```

Note that these unique ID's (aaa's) are all exactly the same.

So, given all these results, how can I access the snapshotted files residing in `/dev/zvol/tank/kvm-images/Ubuntu-Server-20.04@test-01-part3`

Also, keep in mind that I'm very new to ZFS (only read a lot about it during this last week), have zero experience with LVM (except for letting the OS installer use it as a default), so there may be other ways of doing this properly.

Would I be better off by moving the qcow2 file onto a ZFS filesystem and continue using it from there, which would make it easier to create snapshots? I did this and it worked (didn't test the snapshots though), but later I read that this is CoW on CoW and should be avoided, so I'm testing this ZVOL approach.